# How can I reject values from one array based on a parallel array?

Tags: ruby, arrays

Given

```
number_strings = ["ichi", "ni", "san", "ku"]
fixnums = [1, 2, 3, 9]
```

how would I get a list of number_strings where the corresponding fixnum is not even?

```
number_strings.reject.each_with_index do |string, index|
  fixnums.fetch(index).even?
end
```

works, as does

```
pairs = number_strings.zip(fixnums)
pairs.reject{|_, fixnum| fixnum.even?}.map(&:first)
```

but both are a bit verbose.

Answer (score 1):

I think they all come out quite verbose really.

```
Hash[number_strings.zip(fixnums)].select { |k, v| v.odd? }.keys
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `fix` and `select`:

```
fixnums.zip(number_strings).select { |k, v| k.odd? }.map(&:last)
=> ["ichi", "san", "ku"]
```

Comment: It needs `.map(&:first)` at the end.

Comment: `first` returns the list of fixnums which are odd, `last` returns the numbers_strings

Answer (score 0):

I actually think your solutions are fine, the only alternative I can come up with is this and that's as verbose:

```
number_strings.zip(fixnums).map { |str, fn| str if fn.odd? }.compact
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ruby 1.9 you can do:

```
number_strings = ["ichi", "ni", "san", "ku"]
fixnums = [1, 2, 3, 9]

enum = fixnums.each
number_strings.select{ enum.next.odd? }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right to think it's a bit verbose, and that's because Ruby has no syntax for list-comprehensions. A simple abstracion like Enumerable#comprehend -if not as beautiful- comes pretty close (comprehend = map+compact):

```
number_strings.zip(fixnums).comprehend { |s, n| s if n.odd? }
```